# Как полностью очистить объект ввода System.in?

Tags: java, ооп, ascii, поток-ввода

Товарищи, подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне очистить объект ввода System.in? **Класс Scanner не рассматриваем.** Мне нужно именно с ASCII  поработать.
Я хочу зациклить ввод, чтобы если вдруг пользователь ввёл не 1 или 2, то его попросили бы ввести одну из этих цифр заново, и так до тех пор, пока он этого не сделает. Но, очевидно, как только я понимаю, что он ввёл белеберду, мне нужно очистить объект ввода, и всё по новой.
И если в классе Scanner я бы просто использовал .nextLine(), то тут команда System.in.read() извлечёт из этого объекта (не у верен, что правильно выражаюсь) только один символ, а если user ввёл условно "hello", то это уже 5 раз нужно её вызывать; крч я же заранее не знаю, сколько мне потребуется её вызвать, что бы объект System.in оказался пустым.
Как быть?

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main  {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        int code;

        System.out.print("Введите 1 или 2: ");
        while (true)
        {
            code = System.in.read();
            if (code == 49 || code == 50) {
                break;
            }
            else {
                //Необходимо очистить поток ввода.
                System.out.print("Введите 1 или 2: ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Программа завершила свою работу.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно вам подойдет это:

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class SystemIn {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int code;

        System.out.print("Введите 1 или 2: ");
        while (true) {

            code = System.in.read();
            if (code == 49 || code == 50) {
                break;
            } else {
                //Необходимо очистить поток ввода.
                System.in.skip(System.in.available());

                System.out.print("Введите 1 или 2: ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Программа завершила свою работу.");
    }
}
```